# POST to CSV after successful email

Tags: php, csv, email

I have a lead form that sends an email notification when it is filled out. How can i also write this data to a csv on the server if the email is succesful?

Here is my code, right now it simply does nothing, when filling out the form the emails ends, but nothing is written to CSV.

The logic is (which is probably wrong) if it gets to the succ message, open the file.csv and write the $email_f to it and close the csv.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php 
if($_POST['email']){
    $email_f = $_POST['email'];
    $to = "myemail@example.com";
    $subject  = "subject";

    $message = "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <strong>Title</strong><hr />
       <table align='center' width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><td width='30%' style='padding:7px 5px; font-weight:bold;'>Email:</td><td style='padding:7px 5px;'>".$email_f."</td></tr>    
       </table>
    </body>
    </html>";

    //echo $message;
    $headers = "From: <from@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc:' . "\r\n";
    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if($mail)
    {
        echo "succ";
      $file = 'file.csv';
    $file = fopen($file, 'a');
    fputcsv($file, $email_f);
    fclose($file);
}
}






 ?>
```

I also tried this:

```
$list = array ($mail());

    $fp = fopen('/file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Ok getting closer, i added this snippit which opens the file but does not write anything to it, any ideas?:

```
$list = array(

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
    );

    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display; what does it show?

Comment: ^ that was a question btw and just like your question, you also like an answer right? ditto ;-)

Comment: fputcsv $field parameter must be array. Try putting $email_f inside an array

Comment: Be great to see some example of the output file, what you desire and what is currently generated.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for who ever is wondering!

```
$list = array(

   $email_f

    );

    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp,explode(',', $fields));
    }
    fclose($fp);
```